# Laravel — как типизировать Illuminate\Support\Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Мне нужно, чтобы мой метод возвращал коллекцию, но коллекция должна иметь только бъекты заданного типа, например, **ProductItem**

Как это можно реализовать?

Т.е. мне нужно на основе класса **Illuminate\Support\Collection** получить свой класс, **ProductItemCollection**, в который можно будет класть только объекты типа **ProductItem**.

Как это можно реализовать? какие есть варианты? Каким образом можно будет задавать тип для моего контейнера?

Answer (score 1):

Тут стоит подумать, действительно ли Вам нужна функциональность, предоставляемая классом Illuminate\Support\Collection?

Пересмотрел [описание коллекций](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections). Перечитал [документацию по коллекциям](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html). Даже [исходники](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php) посмотрел. И у меня нет простого ответа на Ваш вопрос.

Сдается мне, что с такими запросами Вам надо смотреть не на Eloquent, а в сторону Doctrine. По крайней мере, там есть [документированная возможность расширения класса коллекций](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/derived-collections.html#derived-collections):

> Вы можете создавать собственные классы коллекций, расширяя класс Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. Если семантика __construct отличается от стандартной коллекции ArrayCollection, вы можете переопределить метод createFrom

Нет, конечно же на основе Illuminate\Support\Collection сделать то, что Вам надо, возможно. Я в этом абсолютно уверен. Не уверен только в целесообразности затраты усилий на такую реализацию. Поскольку это потребует не только расширять класс Collection, но и "вписывать" его в "среду обитания". Т.е. делать поставщика услуг, который будет регистрировать новые коллекции, возможно - прописывать для них фасады и т.д.

Если же вопрос только в том, что *в некоем контейнере* могут быть *элементы только одного класса*, и особенно если этот контейнер отдаете Вы и *он должен быть доступен только для чтения* (чтобы лишнего, пользуясь "неразборчивостью" PHP, пользователи контейнера сами не насовали), то мне кажется стоит посмотреть в сторону более простого решения с ограничением доступа "только для чтения", реализовав в собственном классе-коллекции интерфейсы Countable и IteratorAggregate.